# Sorting grouping in a ListView by group name when the grouping property is a list of string

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, mvvm, grouping

I'm working on an application in C# (MVVM) WPF developed by someone else.

In this application some grouping are made on a List of string property in a ListView, the grouping on this property seems to be working but the problem is that **the groups are not sorted alphabetically by group name** in the ListView.

For example :

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvailablePackages);

PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("SupportedOperatingSystems");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SupportedOperatingSystems", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

The property *"SupportedOperatingSystems"* is a *List of string*.

The line : *view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SupportedOperatingSystems", ListSortDirection.Ascending));* is throwing an exception :
**System.InvalidOperationException: 'Failed to compare two elements in the array.'**

Thanks per advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SortDescription only specifies information about the property by which to sort and the sort order.
Using this information, the CollectionView sorts the items by this property.
But for sorting, the type used for the sorted property must have the IComparable interface implemented.
If this interface does not exist, then the error you specified is raised.
No .Net collections, as far as I know, has an implementation of this interface.
To solve the problem, you need to reflect the elements of the original collection into an additional type for the View.
In this type, add a property to which the collection of the original element will be reflected in the converted to type with the IComparable implementation.

Not knowing the details of your implementation, I cannot give you the exact code on how to implement this.
Therefore, I show a very simplified example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SortDescriptionList
{
    public class ListItem
    {
        public IReadOnlyList<string> Strings { get; }
        public string ViewStrings => string.Join(", ", Strings);
        public ListItem(params string[] strings)
            => Strings = Array.AsReadOnly(strings);
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SortDescriptionList
{
    public class StringCollection : List<string>, IComparable, IComparable<IReadOnlyList<string>>
    {
        public int CompareTo(IReadOnlyList<string> other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return 1;

            var minCount = Count;
            if (minCount > other.Count)
                minCount = other.Count;

            if (minCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < minCount; i++)
                {
                    var comp = string.Compare(this[i], other[i]);
                    if (comp != 0)
                        return comp;
                }
            }
            return Count.CompareTo(other.Count);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
            => CompareTo(obj as IReadOnlyList<string>);
    }
}
```

```cs
namespace SortDescriptionList
{
    public class ListItemView
    {
        public StringCollection StringsView { get; }
        public string ViewStrings => Source.ViewStrings;
        public ListItem Source { get; }

        public ListItemView(ListItem source)
        {
            Source = source;
            StringsView = new StringCollection();
            StringsView.AddRange(source.Strings);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace SortDescriptionList
{

    public class ViewModel
    {
        public List<ListItem> ListItems { get; }
            = new List<ListItem>()
            {
                new ListItem("First"),
                new ListItem("Second"),
                new ListItem("Third"),
                new ListItem("Fourth", "Fifth")
            };

        public List<ListItemView> ListItemsView { get; }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            ListItemsView = new List<ListItemView>(ListItems.Select(item => new ListItemView(item)));
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<Window x:Class="SortDescriptionList.SortListWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SortDescriptionList"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="SortListWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <FrameworkElement.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </FrameworkElement.DataContext>
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems}"/>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridView"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemsView}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

The left column displays the DataGrid with the original elements.
And the click for sorting is available only on the "ViewStrings" column, since it is impossible to create a SortDescription for the "Strings" property with the type of a regular collection.

In the right column for the reflective collection, you can enable sorting by the "StringsView" column.
Since the type of this property is no longer a regular list, but a custom StringCollection that implements the IComparable interface and, accordingly, you can create a SortDescription for it.

**Complementing answer**

> Here is the project as zip file

I cannot judge exactly how much this is needed in practice, but the implementation you need is quite complicated and not flexible.
You can sort the elements of the OcAvailablePackages collection by the groups specified in the SupportedPlatforms collection in its elements.

But since you need to sort not by the order of the elements of the SupportedPlatforms collection, but by the sorting order of the SupportedPlatforms elements, you also need to sort them first.
To implement such sorting, I had to come up with a rather complex type:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test_Grouping
{
    public class CompareReadOnlyList<T> : ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IComparable, IComparable<IReadOnlyList<T>>
        where T : IComparable, IComparable<T>
    {
        private readonly T[] array;
        public int Count => array.Length;

        public bool IsReadOnly => true;

        public object SyncRoot => null;
        public bool IsSynchronized => false;

        public T this[int index] => array[index];
        public CompareReadOnlyList(IEnumerable<T> ts)
        {
            array = ts.ToArray();
            Array.Sort(array);
        }

        public CompareReadOnlyList(params T[] ts)
        {
            array = (T[])ts.Clone();
            Array.Sort(array);
        }

        public int CompareTo(IReadOnlyList<T> other)
        {
            if (other == null)
                return 1;

            int minCount = Count;
            if (minCount > other.Count)
            {
                minCount = other.Count;
            }

            if (minCount > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < minCount; i++)
                {
                    int comp = Compare(this[i], other[i]);
                    if (comp != 0)
                    {
                        return comp;
                    }
                }
            }
            return Count.CompareTo(other.Count);
        }

        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            return CompareTo(obj as IReadOnlyList<T>);
        }

        public int Compare(T x, T y)
        {
            return x?.CompareTo(y) ?? -(y?.CompareTo(x) ?? 0);
        }

        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return ((IEnumerable<T>)array).GetEnumerator();
        }

        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return array.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using Infomil.ZSYS.WSUS.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Test_Grouping
{
    public class Package : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Properties

        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set => Set(ref _name, value);
        }

        private CompareReadOnlyList<string> _supportedPlatforms ;
        public CompareReadOnlyList<string> SupportedPlatforms
        {
            get => _supportedPlatforms;
            set => Set(ref _supportedPlatforms, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public Package() { }
        public Package(string name) => Name = name;
        public Package(string name, IEnumerable<string> vs) 
            : this(name)
            => SupportedPlatforms = new CompareReadOnlyList<string>(vs);
        public Package(string name, params string[] vs)
            : this(name, (IEnumerable<string>)vs)
        { }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #endregion
    }
}
```

```cs
using Infomil.ZSYS.WSUS.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Test_Grouping
{
    public class MainWindowVM : ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Properties

        private ObservableCollection<Package> _ocAvailablePackages = new ObservableCollection<Package>();
        public ObservableCollection<Package> OcAvailablePackages
        {
            get => _ocAvailablePackages;
            set => Set(ref _ocAvailablePackages, value);
        }

        private Package _objSelectedPackage;
        public Package ObjSelectedPackage
        {
            get => _objSelectedPackage;
            set => Set(ref _objSelectedPackage, value);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        public MainWindowVM()
        {
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject()))
            {
                return;
            }

            //MessageBox.Show("test");

            OcAvailablePackages.Add(new Package("Package 1", "Platform 2"));

            OcAvailablePackages.Add(new Package("Package 2", "Platform 2", "Platform 4"));

            OcAvailablePackages.Add(new Package("Package 3", "Platform 2", "Platform 1", "Platform 3"));

            OcAvailablePackages.Add(new Package("Package 4", "Platform 3", "Platform 1", "Platform 4"));

            OcAvailablePackages.Add(new Package("Package 5", "Platform 2", "Platform 3"));

            OcAvailablePackages.Add(new Package("Package 6", "Platform 4", "Platform 1", "Platform 3"));

            //Group
            ListCollectionView view = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(OcAvailablePackages);
            view.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(Package.SupportedPlatforms)));

            //The next code row raises an exception (due to List<string>) :
            view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(Package.SupportedPlatforms), ListSortDirection.Ascending));

        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods

        #endregion
    }

}
```

But I really don't like this implementation.
First, I'm not sure that it will always work correctly.
I have not been able to come up with a combination of values to support this assumption, but I think it is.
Secondly, this will not sort the items within the groups.
Since, first, the general collection is sorted, then it is grouped by explicitly specified groups in the collection of elements, these groups are virtual.
And although the ListView displays two dozen rows, in fact there were six items, so the same number remains.

I would implement through an additional type that represents a Package with an explicit breakdown into separate elements for each group:

```cs
using Infomil.ZSYS.WSUS.Mvvm;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test_Grouping
{
    public class PackageRow : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Package Package { get; }

        public string Platform => Package.SupportedPlatforms[index];
        private readonly int index;

        public string Name => Package.Name;

        private PackageRow(Package package, string platform)
        {
            Package = package;
            index = package.SupportedPlatforms.TakeWhile(p => p != platform).Count();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<PackageRow> CreatePackageRows(Package package)
            => package.SupportedPlatforms.Select(platform => new PackageRow(package, platform));

        public static void AddInList(IList<PackageRow> packages, Package package)
        {
            foreach (var pv in CreatePackageRows(package))
            {
                packages.Add(pv);
            }
        }

        public static void RemoveInList(IList<PackageRow> packages, Package package)
        {
            for (int i = packages.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (packages[i].Package == package)
                {
                    packages.RemoveAt(i);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

```cs
            foreach (var pck in OcAvailablePackages)
            {
                PackageRow.AddInList(Packages, pck);
            }

            //Group
            ListCollectionView viewGr = (ListCollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Packages);
            viewGr.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(nameof(PackageRow.Platform)));

            //The next code row raises an exception (due to List<string>) :
            viewGr.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(PackageRow.Platform), ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            viewGr.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription(nameof(PackageRow.Name), ListSortDirection.Ascending));


        }
        public ObservableCollection<PackageRow> Packages { get; }
           = new ObservableCollection<PackageRow>();
```

Archive with the changes made: [Test_Grouping(Le Zvince).7z](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13G6FfiUAcHqEhoS3UuFCOS3JVmVlM1e7/view?usp=sharing)

**Screenshot of the Application.**
The left column is the output using the custom comparator implementation in the property type.
Right - with the division of the original elements into several, one for each group (platform). In this case, you do not need to modify the original Package type.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer EldHasp, after several tries still not able to implement a sort of the Groups (Groups from List<string>).

Comment: Create a small Solution with an example demonstrating the problem in your question.
Upload it to GitHub and provide a link.
I will try to show it with your example so that it is clearer for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your help per advance EldHasp, I have been written a small projet near to what was done in the Application I'm working on. Here is the project as zip file : https://file.io/Ohbet8xkXOUV or https://filebin.net/fbuc1e0i18zpa4a8 In this project I would like to sort the Platforms Groups alphabetically

Comment: Read the addition in my answer.

Comment: **Many thanks for your help @EldHasp !!!** I forget to say that in the application that I'm working on (made by someone else, I'm asked for changes into) I cannot modify the Package.cs class because came from a linked dll that I have not the right to modify (used into other applications). So I will try to use an intermediate class (DTO_Package.cs). I'll let you know if I'm able do it.

Comment: In the last example (breaking one Package into separate lines for each platform), you can use the source code for the Package class.

Comment: Its disadvantage: it does not implement real-time tracking of the SupportedPlatforms collection.
In the source code, this is a regular List.
Therefore, observation of this collection, as I understand it, is not necessary.
Optionally, you can add replacement tracking for the collection itself.

Comment: I'm not able to apply it to the application, groups are not sorted alphabeticaly. I have used your first proposal because I cannot apply the second. Even if I'm not able to apply it to the full application I will accept your answer because I think it's the best I can have. **Many thanks again @EldHasp for your help.**

Comment: I have added a screenshot to my answer.
In both implementations, the groups are in order.
But in the second, the names within the groups are also ordered.
Maybe you somehow misused this implementation?

Comment: If you cannot apply these implementation options for some reason, then clarify the details of your task related to the use problems.
And with them in mind, change your minimal project so that I can make a more useful example for you.

Comment: Please clarify.
Can groups (platforms) change and do they need to be regrouped in real time in case of changes?
That is, the Package.SupportedPlatforms property in its original version is a simple List type and can be replaced.
But does such a change apply in real use AFTER the View is created?

Comment: In the application the load of the Data is made into a `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => { });` does it changes something ?

Comment: And there is a ComboBox to allow to change the grouping.

Comment: These are significant details that may require a very different implementation.
In particular, changing platforms in real time will necessarily require changes to Package.
Since in the current implementation platforms are contained in a simple List, it is impossible to find out when a platform was removed or added from this list.
Could you, taking these details into account, change your simplified example sent by the archive?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this:

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(AvailablePackages.ItemsSource);
PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("SupportedOperatingSystems");
view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
view.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("SupportedOperatingSystems", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but *"AvailablePackages"* is an ObservableCollection<Package> not a ListView (MVVM) so there is no ItemsSource property on this collection.

Comment: If you are using mvvm and have an ObservableCollection, you need to sort it by the column in the ObservableCollection. I need to know more details. Both view model and view